# merge dataframes using fuzzywuzzy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, fuzzywuzzy

I'm trying to merge 2 DataFrames using `fuzzy-wuzzy`.
the `df1` data frame is a table with sales items (150K rows and 30 cols) and `df2` is a table (30K lines and 10 cols) with reference data for sales item name ('`Defproduto`').
I don't have reference data for the sales items but some of them I know they share the same reference data although the name is slightly different.

Example: I have ref data for sales item `aa_XXX_yy_RENT17_zzz_www_class` but I don't have for sales item `aa_XXX_yy_VER17_zzz_www_class`.
Using `fuzzy-wuzzy` I can get the ref data for `aa_XXX_yy_RENT17_zzz_www_class` and assign it in the sales table for all sales Items with name `aa_XXX_yy_VER17_zzz_www_class`

I'm using the follwing code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    df1 = pd.read_excel('/.../dummy_data_examples.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
    df2 = pd.read_excel('/.../refdata_examples.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
    df1['price'] = df1.apply(lambda row:df2.loc[process.extract(row.Defproduto,
                             df2['Defproduto'],limit=1,scorer=fuzz.ratio)[0][2],].price,axis=1)
```

Problem: it is dreadfully slow. It takes about 40sec just for a sample of 100 lines. I have 150K to process (and need to update 5 different characteristics of df1, not just price).

Is there a more efficient/fast process to do this? I've tried different approaches with pandas merge but none able to get the results to need.

Thank you in advance

Comment: PS: for fuzzy-wuzzy I'm using 

        from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
        from fuzzywuzzy import process